# Flask: How can I store user's form-input so that it can be retrieved two requests later

Tags: forms, flask, caching

I am working on a logistics website using Flask.

On route `/step1` the user fills in a form detailing *n* parcels and their attributes.

The form is submitted and a POST request is sent to `/step2` with the following data:

*weight1, length1, width1, height1,

weight2, length2 ...

...

...

*weightn, lengthn, widthn, heightn,

In `/step2` the user fills in the sender and recipient addresses.

This form is submitted as a POST request to `/process-order`

Here's the problem:

How does my `process_order` view retrieve the data provided in both `/step1` and `/step2`

I can think of three solutions - listed below - but I only know how to go about the first one.

1. storing the data submitted in step1 form inside hidden inputs and sending this to the form in `step2.html` and subsequently retrieving this data from the request sent to `process_order` and storing them as an array.
2. Caching
3. flask.g

N.B. This is my very first Flask project and I have zero experience with caching. So please dumb things down for me.

**Update**

Here's my actual code:

```
@main.route('/order', methods=['POST'])
def order():

    # this function is invoked when user submits a form from the home page

    country_from = request.form['country_from']
    country_to = request.form['country_to']

    data = request.form

    parcels = []

    for i in range(1, int(data['parcel_count']) + 1):

        parcel = Parcel(
            weight=data['weight{}'.format(i)],
            length=data['length{}'.format(i)],
            width=data['width{}'.format(i)],
            height=data['height{}'.format(i)],
        )

        parcels.append(parcel)


    weight_units = data['units']
    if weight_units == 'kg':
        distance_units = 'cm'
    else:
        distance_units = '"'


    return render_template('order.html', 
                            countries = COUNTRIES,
                            country_from = country_from,
                            country_to = country_to,
                            parcels = parcels,
                            weight_units = weight_units,
                            distance_units = distance_units,
    )


@main.route('/process-order', methods=['POST'])
def process_order():

    data = request.form

    parcels = []

    # pending
    # how can I retrieve the parcels array again?
```

Note that my view functions are being invoked from the `action` attribute of the forms in my templates (not included here).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can pass the inputs between steps as parameters as follows

```
@app.route('/step1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def step1():
    parcels=[(11,12,13,14),(21,22,23,24),(31,32,33,34)] # contain list of  weights, lengths, widths, heights,
    weight_units ='kg' # another data to pass
    return redirect(url_for('step2',x=parcels,y=weight_units ))

@app.route('/step2/<x>/<y>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def step2(x,y):
    print(x) # console output
    print(y)
    return 'ok'
```

and so on, send all to the next one with more parameters

Comment: Only problem is my step1() view has to return a template rather than a direct redirect to step2(). So my step2() view needs to receive the ```parcels``` array (what you declared as ```x```) from the template as JSON.

Comment: So, do you need to path JSON data?

Comment: I've updated my question with the actual code to make it clearer what I am trying to do

Comment: so, you have an `html` file in which the user fills a form then he presses the submit button which invokes the view function 'order', and in 'order.html' there is a form with a submit button invoking the view function `process_order`. is it right?

Comment: It is better to add the form part of your HTMLs in short, you may need to change the strategy of your scenario.

Comment: Yes exactly as you described. I managed to find a solution using flask_caching.Cache. It seems to be working fine

Comment: So basically I used ```cache.set("parcels", parcels)``` in the ```order``` view and ```cache.get("parcels")``` in the ```process_order``` view. Seems to be working fine however I'm not sure if the ```parcels``` key is specific to the user or a single key across the entire system. For example, if two users are making an order at the same time, will one user's input for parcels override the other's or is a separate parcels key stored for every IP address that connects to the server?